# The application that jhipster generate why not work with angular material2?

Tags: jhipster

I am refering to [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). But the angular material2 does not work in the application that Jhipster generates. And I can't find any error logs.

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatStepperModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {CdkAccordionModule} from '@angular/cdk/accordion';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {BidiModule} from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import {PlatformModule} from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import {ObserversModule} from '@angular/cdk/observers';
import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';

/**
 * NgModule that includes all Material modules that are required to serve the demo-app.
 */
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatDividerModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
        CdkTableModule,
        A11yModule,
        BidiModule,
        CdkAccordionModule,
        ObserversModule,
        OverlayModule,
        PlatformModule,
        PortalModule,
    ]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule {}
```

vandor.scss

```css
/* after changing this file run 'yarn run webpack:build' */
$fa-font-path: '~font-awesome/fonts';
@import 'theme.scss';

@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
/***************************
put Sass variables here:
eg $input-color: red;
****************************/
// Override Boostrap variables
@import "bootstrap-variables";
// Import Bootstrap source files from node_modules
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

app.main.ts

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ProdConfig } from './blocks/config/prod.config';
import { JsueAppModule } from './app.module';

import 'hammerjs';
ProdConfig();
if (module['hot']) {
    module['hot'].accept();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(JsueAppModule)
.then((success) => console.log(`Application started`))
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I found many ways on google, but none that solve my problem.
I doubt its webpack compilation problems, but I don't know how to do.

Maybe angluar version compatibility problems?

I am very helpless. I spent a few days. who can help me?

Comment: JHipster templates use Bootstrap 4, so switching to angular material will require much work: in both HTML and CSS. In the end, you could be better by completely replacing client code generated by JHipster. Simpler alternatives would be to use Bootstrap friendly libraries like PrimeNG or Vmware Clarity which would let you re-use much of JHipster generated code.